# Shift nodes in an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to ask how I can transform the following XML using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

source XML:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <version>1</version>
    </header>
    <line>
        <id> 1 </id>
    </line>
    <line>
        <id> 2 </id>
    </line>
    <subline>
        <id> 1 </id>
    </subline>
    <subline>
        <id> 2 </id>
    </subline>
</root>
```

Target:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <version>1</version>
    </header>
    <line>
        <id> 1 </id>
    </line>
    <subline>
        <id> 1 </id>
    </subline>
    <line>
        <id> 2 </id>
    </line>
    <subline>
        <id> 2 </id>
    </subline>
</root>
```

etc...

Thanks for your support

Comment: I'd recommend "parse", "sort", "write".

Comment: You need to show what you have done. Post your xslt and then ask specific questions.

Comment: Even better, take the time to explain the nature of the transformation you are looking for. Are you wanting to simply swap one `<line>` and one `<subline>`? Would you rather alternate them? Or something else?

Comment: Do you want to sort the elements? If so, have a look at [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#element-sort).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::line or self::subline)]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="line | subline">
        <xsl:sort select="id"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```